# Reference inputText value from link param

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, parameter-passing

I have a `p:inputText`component and a `h:link`that navigate to a different view:

```
<p:inputText id="searchValue" value="#{bean.searchValue}">
   <p:ajax event="keyup" update="search" />
</p:inputText>

<h:link id="search" value="search" outcome="resSearch">
   <f:param name="searchValue" value="#{bean.searchValue}" />
</h:link>
```

The `resSearch`page use the `searchValue`parameter and executes a search based on it, after which it presents the result:

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewParam name="searchValue" value="#{searchBean.searchValue}" />
   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{searchBean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

I'd rather not use ajax to get the value of the `inputText` component. Is it possible to get the value from the `inputText` directly (without using bean properties) and set it as the value of the `param`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a plain HTML GET form.

```
<form action="resSearch.xhtml">
    <input name="searchValue" class="ui-widget ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

Use if necessary CSS to make the button to look like a link, or use JS to submit the form by `<a>`.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957) - check section "Use GET forms in JSF"

Comment: Thanks. Not what I'd hoped for, though it is a solution. I'll go for having the result shown on the same page instead and hide the previous content. As the pages are in viewScope, that way I can use the same bean.